# unit test with actual method in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Hi I’m working on unit test for my project and I want to check a getmin method in an abstract class that is named Measurementool. That method return a minimum value of selectedarea  matrix from current matrix. my project has a rectangle area that is really N*N  matrix .

and I need minimum value inside of matrix. I write unit test for debug and test the getmin value but I don’t see desired value for actual value. selectedarea matrix filled with zero and not set with expected value in test method. I think, it considers two matrix.  matrix with zero value is wrong  when new matrix created as follow:

```
MatrixHolder selectedArea = 
           new MatrixHolder(new double[areaHeight * areaWidth], areaWidth);
```

unit test code:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetMinTest()
{
    AreaMeasurmentTool target = new Rectangle(); 
    double[,] MatrixResult = new double[,] {
    {10, 0, 20, 10, 10},
    {12, 2, 30, 15, 16},
    {19, 0, 43, 10, 17},
    {80, 0, 65, 18, 13},
    {70, 4, 10, 10, 10}};
    double []SelectedArea1 = new double[9]{2, 30, 15, 1, 43, 10, 2, 65, 18};
    MatrixHolder currentMatrix = new MatrixHolder(SelectedArea1, 3); 
    double expected = 1; 
    double actual;
    actual = target.GetMin(currentMatrix);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

and class MeasurementTool:

```
public virtual double GetMin(MatrixHolder currentMatrix)
{
    if (currentMatrix == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("the image Matrix cannot be null.");
    }

    double minValue = 0;

    SetSelectArea(currentMatrix);
    minValue = CalculateMin();
    minValue = Math.Round(minValue, 2);

    return minValue;
}

private void SetSelectArea(MatrixHolder currentMatrix)
{
    PointHolder start = new PointHolder(0, 0);
    PointHolder end = new PointHolder(0, 0);

    SetBoundries(start, end);


    int areaHeight = (end.Y - start.Y);
    int areaWidth = (end.X - start.X);

    MatrixHolder selectedArea = new MatrixHolder(new double[areaHeight * areaWidth], areaWidth);
    for (int i = 0; i < areaHeight; i++)
    {
        int sourceIndex = start.X + (currentMatrix.Witdh * (i + start.Y));
        int targetIndex = areaWidth * i;
        Array.Copy(currentMatrix.Values, sourceIndex
            , selectedArea.Values, targetIndex
            , areaWidth);
    }

    SelectedAreas = selectedArea;
}
```

Comment: So, what's you question? Why your code is incorrect? Why the unit test is not passing? Something else?

Comment: If you know that the input to the method should produce the output you assert, your original method is wrong, this is why you test ;)

Comment: Debug the failing test via the Test menu.